# Can I make an exact copy of a NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can I make an exact copy of a NSTableView ?

I need to copy its content, then I want to change some fonts, differently from the previous one.

Thanks

**Update**:

```
CBTableView *printTableView = [[CBTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)];
[printTableView setDataSource:[self dataSource]];
[printTableView setDelegate:[self delegate]];
[printTableView addTableColumn:[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Title"]];
[self addSubview:printTableView];
[printTableView reloadData];
```

This code is in a subclass of NSTableView. (I just need to create a copy of the current instance to use for printing

WIth this code I create a new table but the number of rows is null.

Comment: Why do you need a different instance for printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after, but you could link two (or more!) table views to the same data source and delegate objects (or the same bindings if you are using those), and therefore return the same content for each one. Your other settings can be done directly against the relevant table view(s) or with some distinction in the relevant delegate methods, depending on what it was you were changing.

Comment: I've done what you say but my new NSTableView doesn't show up. See the code in my question

Comment: What do your delegate / datasource methods look like? Are they getting called for your new table view?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... NSTableView doesn't implement NSCopying, so I don't think there's an easy way to get a deep copy of one of these objects.

I think you would need to allocate a new one, and copy over all the relevant information "by hand" so to speak.

Comment: See the code in the question.. it does't work.. the number of rows is null.